# live broadcasting and video editing

Tags: video-streaming, video-processing, broadcast

i need a name of a software which provides the following:

- ability to read live stream
- buffer it (e.g. 15 minutes)
- ability to edit the buffered stream (cut selected minutes, add blur
  to some arrays)
- output the modified stream (it should be 15 minutes delayed or more)

basically the user would use these 15 minutes to edit the video before it has been broadcasted
P.S: i will use VLC to broadcast the the raw live stream if it's viable...

Comment: unlimited,
but it should be software based, not hardware based.
linux or windows

Comment: In that case, if you do not need this yesterday, I suggest posting this on the VidBlaster forum (www.vidblaster.com) where we can discuss a new "live edit" module for it. All the other necessary functionality is already available.

Comment: I've tested the software it would be great if there's such a module,
you can edit and when you finish just switch to that edited module and play back,